Problem of assigning different indexes to different unseen labels in Pyspark and Scikit-learn
I wonder if there is any algorithm or method to assign different indexes to different unseen labels, and therefore, addressing the 'cold problem' properly.
For example if I use the following Pyspark code
indexers = [
    StringIndexer(inputCol=c, 
                    outputCol="id_{}".format(c)).setHandleInvalid("keep")
    for c in cols
]
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=indexers)

indexer_model = pipeline.fit(data\
                                .where(F.col('period')=='OLD'))

data = indexer_model.transform(data)

I do not solve the problem. For instance if I have 1,000 unseen values, all of them will share exactly the same new index, instead of getting a unique different index each.
Something similar happens with Scikit-learn:
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder


ordinal_encoder = OrdinalEncoder(handle_unknown='use_encoded_value',
                                 unknown_value=-1)


Is this a multiclass classification problem? When you train a model on some data, all the labels are known. And after training the model will predict those classes. So in what scenario are you expecting new labels arising?
